# Get lines surrounding a point

Tags: qgis

Assume we have a road layer and we have a specific point and want to get all roads that surround this point or more precisely form the closest polygon around that point.
I miss a good approach - is there one?
(Also returning junctions closer to the point would be nice but optional)

Comment: Hi, you should give more details and maybe some pictures about your project, it would be easier to answer you...

Comment: Build polygons from the road layer, select the polygon overlaying some point, and select road segments overlaying the selected polygon. Depends on the size of the road layer, and whether it is topological correct, to make this attempt to work.